# What does "tx" mean in callback function when calling Phonegap/Cordova `transaction` method?

Tags: parameters, cordova

From the official doc of Cordova/Phonegap [on transaction method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase), the parameter reads `tx`.

What does `tx` mean?

[image]

Comment: Please make it an answer to get accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tx means transaction object. which give you control to execute query on db which you selected.